# Can you use Javascript Array Map or Reduce when key value pairs are involved?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Taking an array of numbers like this and making a new array with each number the sum of the previous numbers can be done like this:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let total = 0
numbers.map(v => total += v)

// result 
// [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Is there a way to use this same method if the array contains an object with key/value pairs, or do i have to use a different approach?

```
var numbers = [{ val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3, val4: 4 }]
```

The result would be the same keys with the values summed.

```
var numbers = [{ val1: 1, val2: 3, val3: 6, val4: 10 }]
```

edit: all of these answeres worked in the fiddles, but the only one worked in my code was

```
numbers.map(o => Object.assign(...Object.entries(o).map((s => ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: s += v}))(0))));
```

Comment: which result do you expect with an object?

Comment: sorry, edited! Same keys, with the values summed like the original example.

Comment: So, let me get this correct - you with an input of `var obj = { val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3 }` you want the output to be (pseudo-code-y) `{ val1: ${obj.val1}, val2: ${obj.val1 + obj.val2}, val3: ${obj.val1 + obj.val2 + obj.val3} }` is that correct? And if so, do you consider the keys to be in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the single objects and assign the key/value pairs by using a closure over the sum.

```js
var numbers = [{ val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3, val4: 4 }],
    result = numbers.map(o =>
        Object.assign(...Object.entries(o).map((s => ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: s += v}))(0))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow thanks, another great answer. There are so many ways to do this!

Comment: some some reason, this is the only one that actually worked in my real code. i cant even being to figure out why - all the other examples worked in the fiddles, but not in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate the array with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key/value pairs from the object, iterate the pairs with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and rebuild the object with the `total` as value.

Note: the iteration order might change according to the [traversal order of object properties in ES6](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#traversing-the-own-keys-of-an-object).

```js
const numbers = [{ val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3, val4: 4 }]
let total = 0
const result = numbers.map(n => Object.entries(n)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
    total += v;
    r[k] = total;
    return r;
  }, {}));
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `the iteration order might change` that was actually my first thought when I saw this question. I suppose they can just be sorted before running `.reduce` on them but it depends if that's important and what OP would want the order to be.

Comment: Thanks you! this works great. I am going to mark the other arr.map answer correct because it is what im going to end up use in my code, but this is a great example of .reduce!

Comment: @vlaz - unless there are numeric/symbol keys, the order should stay the same.

Comment: @OriDrori well, if you start with `{ val4: 4, val2: 2, val1: 1, val3: 3 }` (for whatever reason) then you are going to get the order 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 3, yet you might want to process them in order 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4. Hence why you might sort them.

Comment: @vlaz - indeed. You need to set the keys in the original object, in the required order of iteration, or as you suggested sort them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```js
var total = 0;
            
var array =[{ val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3, val4: 4 }]
array.map(element => Object.keys(element).map(k => { 
   total += element[k]; 
   element[k] = total; 
}));
           
console.log(array);
```

It will iterate trough array and sumarize all objects properties.

Comment: Why use `.map` and not `forEach` at the very least?

Comment: This is great. The other .reduce answer is correct too but this is the more elegant solution. Will accept this answer!

Comment: @vlaz It was my choice. `forEach()` will do same result. `map()` instead returns array which is not necessary here which I agree. But in general `map()` is faster than `forEach()`.

Comment: i love all the different ways to do this, but yours Kat is the top dog!

Comment: did you change the code? it doesnt work now, your original post was spot on

Comment: @user3869231 I updated. Now it will display `20` in `alert()`. Which issue you have?

Comment: Oh, i wanted the new object/array returned, the total 20 doesnt matter. 
arr.map(i => Object.keys(i).map(k => total += i[k] )) returns what i need, thanks!

Comment: @user3869231 Sorry, I didn't understand what you exactly need. I updated based on your requiremenst

Answer (score 1):

Standard way to iterate object is to use `Object.keys` array.
Way to build accumulated object is `Array.reduce`.

```js
var numbers = [{ val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 3, val4: 4 }];
var total = 0;
var mapped = Object.keys(numbers[0]).reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = total+=numbers[0][key], acc), {});

console.log(mapped);
```